# Default and Production configuration in Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have default application properties in classpath. I need to override this from external properties from file if it exists.

Now loading properties seems as follow:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:some-configuration.properties</value>
            <!--...-->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is there ways to do this?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443534/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-use-external-properties-file

Comment: @hasnae Thanks, it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add property to bean

```
<property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
```

and specify your external properties file in locations

```
<value>file:/env/another-configurations.properties</value>
```